# What is the best expression used by an employee to appreciate his/her employer?

Tags: culture

Assume that the employer gives a presentation to the public audience. After the presentation, you as the employee want to appreciate it.

What is the best expression used by an employee to appreciate his/her employer?

For example, is it polite to say "Anata no happyoo ha ii desu." ?

Comment: Maybe something like `お疲れ様でした。Xさんの発表とてもよかったです。`

Comment: How about 「(name)+(title like 課長/部長)のプレゼン、大変[たいへん]勉強[べんきょう]になりました。」?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- It is not appropriate to say あなた to your boss. Call by the title plus the name.
- happyo → happyoo
- ha → wa
- Using the non past form here is wrong. Use the past tense.

Comment: But is it polite for the employees to evaluate the boss' performance?

Comment: I thought that that was not questioned in your question. If it is something that the employee clearly has the ability to evaluate, it is not rude unless the evaluation is low.

Comment: @sawa - "ha" is often used in romaji so that beginners will quickly learn to use `は` for the 'wa' particle.

Comment: @istrasci I know that, but that is wrong. Romanization is the transcription of the sound, not the spelling. And if they do that, they may learn to write correctly, but pronounce wrongly.

Comment: @sawa Saying that it is wrong is quite... wrong itself. People who learn は (particle) as romaji "ha" will still pronounce it the same way as you do when you use the romaji "wa". So it does in fact represent the sound. Similarly, people who learn し as romaji "si" will pronounce it as IPA ɕi. They have mapped the roman letters to different sounds than other romanization methods. Nothing is wrong about it though.

Comment: @sawa Nihon-shiki Romanization would use "ha", not "wa". If you said "This is incorrect for Hepburn Romanization", or "Nihon-shiki is a bad Romanization scheme", that'd be a legitimate statement, but merely saying that "ha" is wrong is misleading.

Comment: @atlantiza The shi sound is indeed si in the underlying representation and there is indeed a phonological rule that maps si to shi. But there is no synchronic rule that maps ha to wa. If so, you would have to pronounce hashi as washi.

Comment: @Andrew Some people do that but that is wrong unless it is used for a very special purpose such as describing the kana system of Japanese.

Comment: @istrasci Romaji was not designed for beginners (non natives), so the convenience of the beginners could not have come into play.

Comment: @sawa Someone used to this style knows that particle は written as "ha" is pronounced differently from はし written as "hashi" (or hasi if they prefer). I know people who use this romanization method and they are conscious of the different pronunciations. Although you may not see the rule, it is there. It's not up to us to decide what romanization methods people use.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- スピーチ／演説{えんぜつ}お疲{つか}れ様{さま}でした。
- 今日は、*社長{しゃちょう}／Aさん*のお話{はなし}を聞{き}くことができて本当{ほんとう}によかったです。
- *社長／Aさん*のお話、たいへん[感銘{かんめい}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%84%9F%E5%8B%95)を受{う}けました。
- *社長／Aさん*のお話、たいへん感動{かんどう}を受{う}けました。
- *社長／Aさん*のお話、たいへん勉強{べんきょう}になりました。
- *社長／Aさん*のお話、たいへん**ため**になりました。

Mostly inconsequential, but someone could object the use of 発表{はっぴょう} when referring to a distinguished figure such as one's superiors in rank.

Also note the use of Hiragana for 大変{たいへん} in the written language when you are praising someone or *want to appear smart or knowledgeable*. You can use 大変 in Kanji when you talk about something negative or adverse:

- 今日の仕事{しごと}、本当に大変でした。